# Why I can't debug watch face on moto 360

Tags: wear-os, moto-360, watch-face-api

I can see the logs below but I can not see the watch face on my watch.

```
Waiting for device.
Target device: motorola-moto_360-localhost:4444
Uploading file
    local path: /Users/.../AndroidStudioProjects/WatchFace1/Wearable/build/outputs/apk/Wearable-debug.apk
    remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.example.android.wearable.watchface
Installing com.example.android.wearable.watchface
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.example.android.wearable.watchface"
pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.example.android.wearable.watchface
Success


Waiting for process: com.example.android.wearable.watchface
```

I have waited for a long time but nothing happened.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I see that the apk was successfully installed on the watch. If you long tap on the watch in order to select a watch face, do you see yours in the list? After selecting it you will be able to debug it.

Basically, what I assume it happens is that you install the watch face, but you don't actually run it.

Answer (score 0):

you have to select your watchface from moto 360 by touch and hold on the screen of moto 360 then by swiping the watchfaces then you can debug your watchface.